# How to dereference HDF5 references in Python?

Tags: python, hdf5

Sometimes I get the following arrays from my HDF5 file:

```
val1 = {ndarray} [<HDF5 object reference> <HDF5 object reference> <HDF5 object reference>]
```

If I try to dereference it with HDF5 file object

```
f[val[0]]
```

I get an error

```
Argument 'ref' has incorrect type (expected h5py.h5r.Reference, got numpy.object_)
```

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this question while trying to answer what turned out to be basically [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733052/read-hdf5-file-into-numpy-array) in another form. A dataset containing references to other objects is a bit of an awkward situation in HDF5, but you can actually read them in a pretty straightforward way. The idea is to get the *name* of the referenced object, and then just read that object directly from the file.

Given a single HDF5 reference, `ref`, and a file, `file`, you can return the name of the referenced dataset by doing:

```
>>> name = h5py.h5r.get_name(ref, file.id)
```

Then just read the actual dataset itself, as usual:

```
>>> data = file[name].value # ndarray with the data in it.
```

So to read all the referenced datasets, just `map` this process across the whole dataset of references.

Comment: might be nice to include some searchable terms.  For me, i was trying to unpack MATLAB matfiles, specifically the large ones that are not loadable via `scipy.io`