# Read HDF5 file into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have the following code to read a hdf5 file as a numpy array:

```
hf = h5py.File('path/to/file', 'r')
n1 = hf.get('dataset_name')
n2 = np.array(n1)
```

and when I print `n2` I get this:

```
Out[15]:
array([[<HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>,
        <HDF5 object reference>, <HDF5 object reference>...
```

How can I read the `HDF5 object reference` to view the data stored in it?

Comment: You can also have a look about how to read ahdf5 into a pandas dataframe and from there to inspect the contained information, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74127100/5838180

Answer (score 38):

The easiest thing is to use the `.value` attribute of the HDF5 dataset.

```
>>> hf = h5py.File('/path/to/file', 'r')
>>> data = hf.get('dataset_name').value # `data` is now an ndarray.
```

You can also slice the dataset, which produces an actual ndarray with the requested data:

```
>>> hf['dataset_name'][:10] # produces ndarray as well
```

But keep in mind that in many ways the `h5py` dataset acts like an `ndarray`. So you can pass the dataset itself unchanged to most, if not all, NumPy functions. So, for example, this works just fine: `np.mean(hf.get('dataset_name'))`.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood the question originally. The problem isn't loading the numerical data, it's that the dataset actually *contains* HDF5 references. This is a strange setup, and it's kind of awkward to read in `h5py`. You need to *dereference* each reference in the dataset. I'll show it for just one of them.

First, let's create a file and a temporary dataset:

```
>>> f = h5py.File('tmp.h5', 'w')
>>> ds = f.create_dataset('data', data=np.zeros(10,))
```

Next, create a reference to it and store a few of them in a dataset.

```
>>> ref_dtype = h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)
>>> ref_ds = f.create_dataset('data_refs', data=(ds.ref, ds.ref), dtype=ref_dtype)
```

Then you can read one of these back, in a circuitous way, by getting its name ,and then reading from that actual dataset that is referenced.

```
>>> name = h5py.h5r.get_name(ref_ds[0], f.id) # 2nd argument is the file identifier
>>> print(name)
b'/data'
>>> out = f[name]
>>> print(out.shape)
(10,)
```

It's round-about, but it seems to work. The TL;DR is: get the name of the referenced dataset, and read directly from that.

**Note:**

The `h5py.h5r.dereference` function seems pretty unhelpful here, despite the name. It returns the ID of the referenced object. This can be read from directly, but it's *very* easy to cause a crash in this case (I did it several times in this contrived example here). Getting the name and reading from that is much easier.

**Note 2:**

As stated in the [release notes for h5py 2.1](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/whatsnew/2.1.html?highlight=.value#dataset-value-property-is-now-deprecated), the use of `Dataset.value` property is deprecated and should be replaced by using `mydataset[...]` or `mydataset[()]` as appropriate.

> The property `Dataset.value`, which dates back to h5py 1.0, is deprecated and will be removed in a later release. This property dumps the entire dataset into a NumPy array. Code using `.value` should be updated to use NumPy indexing, using `mydataset[...]` or `mydataset[()]` as appropriate.

Comment: I'm trying that but I still get the same `HDF5 object reference` when I print the `data` variable

Comment: Ahh, I think I know what's going on. The dataset you're trying to load is actually made up of HDF5 references. It's not numerical data. You can verify this by doing `h5ls` or `h5dump` on the file. In this case, I don't know how you can read from the referenced dataset in `h5py`.

Comment: It looks like you can use the `h5py.H5R` module to dereference the dataset. Can you try: `h5py.h5r.dereference(hf['dataset_name'])`?

Comment: When I try that, I get this error message 
`TypeError: dereference() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)`

Comment: When I list the keys by doing `with h5py.File('path/to/file, 'r') as hdf:
    ls = list(hdf.keys())
    print('List of datasets in this file: \n', ls)`

I get `List of datasets in this file: 
 ['#refs#', 'data_set']`

Not sure if this would help or not

Comment: Do you want to load `#refs#` or `data_set`?

Comment: `data_set` is what I'm trying to load

Comment: I'm still unable to read the `HDF5 object reference`.  Sorry but I can't see how your example is relevant to my question.  I've been trying for days and will post an answer here so others don't have to go through this.

Comment: You can use the name of the referenced object to access it directly in the file, which is the relevance of my answer to your question. But Pierre de Buyl's answer is actually easier.

Comment: As of 2021 year, using the code in this answer gives a message: `H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a direct approach to read hdf5 file as a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

hf = h5py.File('path/to/file.h5', 'r')
n1 = np.array(hf["dataset_name"][:]) #dataset_name is same as hdf5 object name 

print(n1)
```

Answer (score 8):

h5py provides intrinsic method for such tasks: `read_direct()`

```
hf = h5py.File('path/to/file', 'r')
n1 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=numpy_type)
hf['dataset_name'].read_direct(n1)
hf.close()
```

The combined steps are still faster than `n1 = np.array(hf['dataset_name'])` if you `%timeit`. The only drawback is, one needs to know the shape of the dataset beforehand, which can be assigned as an attribute by the data provider.

Answer (score 6):

HDF5 has a simple object model for storing [datasets](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html) (roughly speaking, the equivalent of an "on file array") and organizing those into groups (think of directories). On top of these two objects types, there are much more powerful features that require layers of understanding.

The one at hand is a "[Reference](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5R.html)". It is an internal address in the storage model of HDF5.

h5py will do all the work for you without any calls to obscure routines, as it tries to follow as much as possible a dict-like interface (but for references, it is a bit more complex to make it transparent).

The place to look for in the docs is [Object and Region References](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html). It states that to access an object pointed to by reference `ref`, you do

```
 my_object = my_file[ref]
```

In your problems, there are two steps:
1. Get the reference
2. Get the dataset

```
# Open the file
hf = h5py.File('path/to/file', 'r')
# Obtain the dataset of references
n1 = hf['dataset_name']
# Obtain the dataset pointed to by the first reference
ds = hf[n1[0]]
# Obtain the data in ds
data = ds[:]
```

If the dataset containing references is 2D, for instance, you must use

```
ds = hf[n1[0,0]]
```

If the dataset is scalar, you must use

```
data = ds[()]
```

To obtain the all the datasets at once:

```
all_data = [hf[ref] for ref in n1[:]]
```

assuming a 1D dataset for n1. For 2D, the idea holds but I don't see a short way to write it.

To get a full idea of how to roundtrip data with references, I wrote short "writer program" and a short "reader program":

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# Open file                                                                                    
myfile = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', 'w')

# Create dataset                                                                               
ds_0 = myfile.create_dataset('dataset_0', data=np.arange(10))
ds_1 = myfile.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=9-np.arange(10))

# Create a data                                                                                
ref_dtype = h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)

ds_refs = myfile.create_dataset('ref_to_dataset', shape=(2,), dtype=ref_dtype)

ds_refs[0] = ds_0.ref
ds_refs[1] = ds_1.ref

myfile.close()
```

and

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# Open file                                                                                    
myfile = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', 'r')

# Read the references                                                                          
ref_to_ds_0 = myfile['ref_to_dataset'][0]
ref_to_ds_1 = myfile['ref_to_dataset'][1]

# Read the dataset                                                                             
ds_0 = myfile[ref_to_ds_0]
ds_1 = myfile[ref_to_ds_1]

# Read the value in the dataset                                                                
data_0 = ds_0[:]
data_1 = ds_1[:]

myfile.close()

print(data_0)
print(data_1)
```

You will notice that you cannot use the standard convenient and easy NumPy like syntax for reference datasets. This is because HDF5 references are not representable with the NumPy datatypes. They must be read and written one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Hi this is the way I use to read hdf5 data, hope it could be usefull to you

```
with h5py.File('name-of-file.h5', 'r') as hf:
    data = hf['name-of-dataset'][:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers suggested previously but none of them worked for me.
For example, read_direct() method gives an error 'Operation not defined for data type class'. The .value method also does not work. After a lot of struggling I could get around with using the reference itself to get the numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('file.mat','r')
data2get = f.get('data2get')[:]

data = np.zeros([data2get.shape[1]])
for i in range(data2get.shape[1]):
    data[i]  = np.array(f[data2get[0][i]])[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For loading in large .mat files, saved in MATLAB under version 7.3
i.e., if your mat file is saved with '-v7.3'

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

path = '/yourfile.mat' 
f = h5py.File(path)
```

type:

```
list(f.keys())
```

Lists your data. if mat file is saved as 'finance.mat', this returns `['finance']`

then:

```
fin= f['finance']
fin_arr = np.asarray(fin)
```