# Is there a way to write a multidimensional C array to .npy format with C code, so that we could read the array in python numpy later?

Tags: python, c, numpy, io

I am doing some scientific computation, and I produce data with a C program and analyses using python. I want to export an array from C to python.

So far what I am doing is to write the C array, which is multidimensional (More than 2), into a csv file, and reading it from python np.genfromtxt and unwrapping it using the .reshape method. I think it would be a huge improvement if I could directly write a .npy file and call np.load. Is there any library in C that could do this?

Comment: This code is maturing: https://github.com/oysteijo/npy_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPY file format is an internal file format of Numpy. While there are few (non-standard) libraries like [this](https://sr.ht/%7Equf/cnpy/) or [this](https://github.com/llohse/libnpy) or even [this](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy), the file format is relatively simple and documented by Numpy [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html). It can change in the future and the libraries may not be up to date.

Alternatively, a better solution is certainly to load/save your file using the [**HDF5** standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format). It is widely supported by many fast/HPC libraries and supported by Numpy too (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733052/read-hdf5-file-into-numpy-array) for more information). HDF5 also provide more advanced features like reading a slice or parallel read/writes for HPC applications.